# Laravel RedirectIfAuthenticated not working after moving from XAMPP to Laragon

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, laragon

Previously I used **XAMPP**, then migrated to **Laragon**. when still using **XAMPP** my application is still functioning properly, but after migrating to Laragon it turns out that my application has an error, namely **RedirectIfAuthenticated** does not work, and even though the **User** name that is currently logged appears in the application header, but the **session** user that is currently logged does not appear when debug on **Clockwork**. Has anyone ever experienced the same thing here? how is the solution, I see on Google it seems that no one has discussed this issue.

this is RedirectifAuthenticated
[image: redirectifauthenticated]

this is my login controller
[image: logincontroller]

this is master layout, i use **auth check** here
[image: master layout, i use auth check here]

this clockwork display, to debug my app
[image: clockwork]

Comment: Have you cleared all your local cache and laravel cache?

Comment: yes, i have did it